# ¿Cómo puedo agrupar en jerarquía los datos en Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, agrupación

Tengo los siguientes datos:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
ciudades = [
  {"ciudad": "Madrid", "pais": "España", "continente": "Europa", "valor": 8},
  {"ciudad": "Barcelona", "pais": "España", "continente": "Europa", "valor": 6},
  {"ciudad": "Valencia", "pais": "España", "continente": "Europa", "valor": 5},
  {"ciudad": "Lausana", "pais": "Suiza", "continente": "Europa", "valor": 9},
  {"ciudad": "ginebra", "pais": "Suiza", "continente": "Europa", "valor": 6},
  {"ciudad": "zurich", "pais": "Suiza", "continente": "Europa", "valor": 5},
  {"ciudad": "Paris", "pais": "Francia", "continente": "Europa", "valor": 8},
  {"ciudad": "Nueva York", "pais": "Estados Unidos", "continente": "America", "valor": 8},
  {"ciudad": "San Francisco", "pais": "Estados Unidos", "continente": "America", "valor": 7},
  {"ciudad": "Los Angeles", "pais": "Estados Unidos", "continente": "America", "valor": 6},
  {"ciudad": "Toronto", "pais": "Canadá", "continente": "America", "valor": 6}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(ciudades)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo con pandas agrupar en jerarquía los datos para conseguir el siguiente formato de salida?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Podemos empezar por usar un índice jerárquico, para que todo quede agrupado por continente primero, después por país, y finalmente por ciudad:

```py
table = df.set_index(["continente", "pais", "ciudad"])
```

Resultado:

```html
                                         valor
continente pais           ciudad              
Europa     España         Madrid             8
                          Barcelona          6
                          Valencia           5
           Suiza          Lausana            9
                          ginebra            6
                          zurich             5
           Francia        Paris              8
America    Estados Unidos Nueva York         8
                          San Francisco      7
                          Los Angeles        6
           Canadá         Toronto            5
```

Ahora podemos procesar esta tabla agrupando por niveles, y en cada nivel calculamos la suma total, e iteramos por el subnivel para hacer lo mismo. Los resultados los vamos recogiendo en un diccionario cuya clave sea el nombre (continente, pais o ciudad según corresponda en cada nivel) y cuyo valor sea la suma de ese nivel.

Ya que son tres niveles (contando el nivel "ciudad") habrá tres bucles anidados. Para mayor claridad a la hora de mostrar la tabla, añadiré espacios por la izquierda en el nombre del pais o ciudad, para que quede indentado como en una jerarquía.

Este sería el código:

```py
result = {}
for k,d in table.groupby(level=0):
  result.update({k: sum(d.valor)})
  for k, d in d.groupby(level=1):
    result.update({f"  {k}": sum(d.valor)})
    for k, d in d.groupby(level=2):
      result.update({f"    {k}": sum(d.valor)})
```

El diccionario resultante se puede convertir en una tabla pandas:

```
resultado = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result, orient="index", columns=["valor"])
```

Y esta es la tabla resultante:

```html
                   valor
America               26
  Canadá               5
    Toronto            5
  Estados Unidos      21
    Los Angeles        6
    Nueva York         8
    San Francisco      7
Europa                47
  España              19
    Barcelona          6
    Madrid             8
    Valencia           5
  Francia              8
    Paris              8
  Suiza               20
    Lausana            9
    ginebra            6
    zurich             5
```

#### Generalización

Los tres bucles anidados valen para este caso en que hay tres niveles en el multi-index. En un caso general se puede hacer una función que cree el diccionario necesario recursivamente:

```py
def aggregate_levels(table, r, level=0, column="valor"):
  if level>=len(table.index.levshape):
    return
  for k, d in table.groupby(level=level):
    r[f"{'  '*level}{k}"] = sum(d[column])
    aggregate_levels(d, r, level+1)
```

Esto agrega por totales cada nivel, hasta llegar al más bajo. Se usaría así en este caso:

```
result = {}
aggregate_levels(table, result)
```

y daría en este caso el mismo resultado antes mostrado (una vez convertido a DataFrame como se mostró antes)

Answer (score 0):

Si no te importa el orden de tus datos el siguiente código te sirve. Solamente hice diferentes grupos y cambie la etiqueta a 'lugares'.

```
valor_por_pais =  df.groupby("pais", as_index = False).sum().rename(columns={'pais':'lugar'})

valor_por_continente =  df.groupby("continente",as_index = False).sum().rename(columns={'continente':'lugar'})
```

Para los datos por país creé un nuevo dataframe:

```
valor_por_ciudad =  pd.concat([df['ciudad'], df['valor']], axis=1, keys=['lugar', 'valor'])
```

Al final hice una concatenación, ignorando los indices de los dataframes originales.

```
df_lugares = pd.concat([valor_por_continente, valor_por_pais,  valor_por_ciudad ], ignore_index = True)
```

Ahora, por si te interesa tenerlos organizados por continente, puedes mantener como índice la columna de 'continente' y al final organizarlos:

```
valor_por_pais =  df.groupby(["continente", "pais"], as_index = False).sum().rename(columns={'pais':'lugar'}).set_index('continente')

valor_por_continente =  df.groupby("continente", as_index = False).sum().rename(columns={'continente':'lugar'})
valor_por_continente.index = valor_por_continente['lugar']

valor_por_ciudad =  pd.concat([df['ciudad'], df['valor'], df['continente']], axis=1, keys=['lugar', 'valor', 'continente']).set_index('continente')

df_lugares = pd.concat([valor_por_continente, valor_por_pais,  valor_por_ciudad ])
df_lugares.sort_index(inplace=False)
```